# How to Fixing error that outputs <function points at 0x000001C2267A9D30>?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently making a small game, and I'm working on the points system. I put this at the beginning of the program:

```
points = 0
```

Then, I made a function so that the player can call it at any time to see how many points they have gathered:

```
def points():
    print(f'You have {points} points.')
```

It all seems fine, until I call the function. Instead of the output I want, which would be 0 since no points have been accumulated, it prints this out:

```
You have <function points at 0x000001DF208A9D30> points.
```

I've tried to use str() and string concatenation, but either it doesn't work at all, or it prints out the exact same type of error. Any help would be appreciated, and I'm sorry if it seems like too much of a basic question, I am just a beginner! :)

Comment: That's not an error, that's how Python print out a function if you tell it to. Which you are, because `points` is a function - the function your `print` statement is inside. Use a different function name if you're trying to print some `points` variable from an outer scope.

Comment: Never name 2 different things the same, don't re-use name from your own variables for other purpose, don't reuse name from a lib you imported. One name = one thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rename either the variable or the function name.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
userPoints=0
# ... More functions and variables here
def callPoints():
    return userPoints
```

Thanks, Robin Zigmond and azro for pointing out the error!